# Is there any programming project that implements one quantum error correction code or demonstrates it?

Tags: programming, error-correction

A gigantic list of **all the error correction codes(Classical Domain, Quantum Domain, Classical-quantum Domain)**, see https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/all

---

There are lots of [quantum error correction code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction). e.g.

- Bit flip code
- Sign flip code
- Shor code(a.k.a., Peter Shor's 9-qubit-code)
- Bosonic codes(including cat, Gottesman-Kitaev-Preskill (GKP), and binomial codes.)
- [stabilizer code(also called additive codes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_code)
- [CSS(named by Calderbank, Shor,and Steane)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_code)
- [quantum convolutional code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_convolutional_code)
- [Bacon–Shor code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%E2%80%93Shor_code)
- [Steane code(namely, Steane's 7-qubit code)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steane_code)
- [Toric code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_code) (an example of topological quantum error correcting code, also an example of a stabilizer code)
- [gnu code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnu_code)
- [Five-qubit error correcting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-qubit_error_correcting_code)
- entanglement-assisted stabilizer formalism as an extension of the standard stabilizer formalism (considering quantum entanglement)

The list is not consistent with taxology, for the verison under taxology, see [the graph](https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/code_graph#domain_quantum_domain).

---

My question is:
Is there any programming project that **implements** one Quantum error correction code or **demonstrates** it?

I also want to know which one is the most practical?

Comment: [Stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim) is a python package that allows you to simulate a variety of [stabilizer codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_code).

Comment: @banercat thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

[Three-coupler and iswap and walking surface codes](https://github.com/Strilanc/midout)

> [image]

[Pair-measurement surface code](https://github.com/Strilanc/cairo-surface-code)

> [image]

[Honeycomb code](https://github.com/Strilanc/honeycomb-boundaries)

> [image]

[Bacon-Shor code and Fractal Bacon-Shor code](https://github.com/Strilanc/more-bacon-less-threshold)

> [image]

You may also want to look at the example circuits in [crumble](https://algassert.com/crumble), which include for example a distance 3 surface code:

> [image] [image]

Comment: Wow ,useful Things. +1)